# Database clog up

Tags: php, mysql

I am in the process of building a messaging section for my website where clients and admin can send each other messages. I am using mysql. I am just curious, My database is structured as

(message, recipient, sender and time send)

Every time a message is sent it creates a new row in the database. My question is this efficient. Because when the user logs into there account the database will have to query there conversation. I have it so it only shows the last 10. Although will this overtime slow down when there are more database rows with more messages. And if possible, How can i fix this issue. Pease ask as many questions as possible.

Comment: you can make use of relational tables; that's where a lot of mysql/sql's power/functionalitly lies

Comment: Thanks, @Fred-ii- I will look that up

Comment: if you dont want to keep all the messages maybe delete the ones older than X every day. other than that, not sure what you are asking. But a db table can handle may millions of rows with out issue

Comment: you're welcome. Plus, pagination could also come of use. Just make sure you use a prepared statement, should there be any user input.

Comment: As long as both recipient and sender are indexed and probably holding the id in a user table, there should not be much of a performance issue. You should only store as many messages as you need and probably delete old ones after a while to make sure the database does not grow too much. If you are really worried about the database growing too big, you can also consider splitting it up, for example by month and year and only display and search the tables of the current month until the user loads older messages (much like in Skype)

Comment: Although i already have multiple table. and there is already as limited data as i can have in the messages table. @Fred-ii-

Comment: i am going to add pagination, Although I'm not confident with it. it will be useful to see older messages. @Fred-ii-

Comment: well, as already stated; you can choose to delete the tables if they're no longer needed, but I would archive them and use dated tables. I know that could take some doing, but if you think about how to structure included files and do some auto-dating folder/file naming, you'll see that it'll be worth it.

Comment: @Lupinity So if my query are more precise to exactly what it is searching for it will be better.

Comment: Dated tables would work really well. @Fred-ii- I will definitely keep this in mind.

Comment: it's an option. Just make sure that all your tables are properly indexed and don't load too much data that's not needed and columns. `SELECT *` is often a performance killer if you have many columns. So it's best to `SELECT col1, col2, col3` in many cases of relational tables.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I often select the certain column instead of every single column in the table

Comment: Ok. Well, You could also consider posting on Database Adminstrators   http://dba.stackexchange.com/ as you may get a better response and going through some of the questions in that part of Stack.